# How to clone Raspberry-pi OS to Image (e.g ISO)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, clone, raspbian

I need a tool to clone only the used parts of my Raspberry-pi OS to a an Image(e.g ISO). Is there any tool to do it?

I tried with dd (Linux command)  however, it clones the whole disk to an ISO and not only the used part.

I tried PiClone which did clone only the used parts of the disk, however it does not save the clone to an image, it can only Clone to a chip.

Comment: Have you tried using [ddrescue or dd_rescue with its sparse option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17087/clone-whole-partition-or-hard-drive-to-a-sparse-file)? Or the `-conv sparse` option to `dd`?

Comment: * ddrescue -S -b8M /dev/sdd test.img
* dd if=/dev/sdd of=test.img conv=sparse bs=512

I tried with both, but it didn't reduce the image size, My raspberry sd card size is 16 GB, I wanna make an ISO around 4 GB.

Comment: Remember that both cases (.. and everything will, unless you use something that just duplicates the file system and not creates an actual image) require the disk to be initially initialized with zeroes, so that it can tell which parts have been used or not

Comment: If you make the filesystem only big enough for what is needed (i.e. _don’t_ expand to fit the card) then you can copy the entire SD to disk image and then clip that image to no smaller than the file system size. And yes BEFORE creating the filesystem, zero the entire SD card because that makes the clipped image much more more compressible.